# Docker / Oracle Database / Change Port 1521

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose

I have set an Oracle docker image (https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles) which by default is running on port 1521.
I would like to change the port in the Image to 1531.

I know that in the docker-compose I can set "1531:1521" BUT the other container still searching for port 1521 in the created network.

I tried to modify the port referenced in the Dockerfile of the version I want to use (19.3.0) and also in the createDB.sh but when I try to connect with the SID it fails, the listener is not working as expected.

Anybody already succeeded?

Update 1:
Here is the error message when I try to connect to the database after I changed the port.

`SQL> CONNECT sys/HyperSecuredPassword@ORCLCDB AS sysdba; ERROR: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor`

Update 2:
I have the following docker-compose.yaml to set up the other containers for my project.

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  hadea-database:
    image:  hadea_oracle_1521:19.3.0
    container_name: hadea_oracle_1930
    ports:
      - "1521:1521"
    environment:
      - ORACLE_SID=ORCLCDB
      - ORACLE_PDB=ORCLPDB
      - ORACLE_PWD=Oracle4System
      - ORACLE_MEM=2000
    volumes:
      - ./database/OracleDB/oradata:/opt/oracle/oradata
      - ./database/OracleDB/setup:/opt/oracle/scripts/setup
      - ./database/OracleDB/startup:/opt/oracle/scripts/startup
    networks:
      - hadea-network

  hadea-maildev:
    image: maildev/maildev
    container_name: hadea_maildev
    command: bin/maildev --web 80 --smtp 25 --hide-extensions STARTTLS
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    networks:
      - hadea-network

  hadea-server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: hadea_back
    environment:
      - HTTP_PORT=3000
      - HTTP_HOST=0.0.0.0
      - DATABASE_HOST=hadea-database
      - DATABASE_PORT=1521 # CONTAINER port NOT the HOST port
      - DATABASE_SID=ORCLCDB
      - MAIL_HOST=hadea-maildev
      - MAIL_PORT=25 # CONTAINER port NOT the HOST port
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    volumes:
      - ./server:/usr/src/app
    networks:
      - hadea-network
    depends_on:
      - hadea-database
      - hadea-maildev

  hadea-front:
    build:
      context: ./front
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: hadea_front
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
      - "3001:3001"
    volumes:
      - ./front:/usr/src/app
    networks:
      - hadea-network
    depends_on:
      - hadea-database
      - hadea-maildev
      - hadea-server

networks:
  hadea-network:
```

Comment: Which 'other' container are you talking about? You cannot change the internal exposed port, as 1521 and 5500 (only express) are the only exposed ports, so you have to use them and map them to the outside.

Comment: @Marco I have updated my question by adding the docker-compose YAML file. The fact is that if I change the host port indeed I have access from my host. But when my backend tries to access the database service, it use the database container port and not (logical has you have to use the service name for the server to point to) the host port

Comment: I can't see a build option in the docker readme to specify the port, so I guess, you have to  edit https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/19.3.0/createDB.sh to your desired port and then build the image yourself.

Comment: I tried to change 1521 by my desired port in that file and in the Dockerfile (port.listener) (https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/19.3.0/Dockerfile) but then my backend (and even sqldevelopper on my host) are not able to connect. 

Even when I docker -it the database container I have

```SQL> CONNECT sys/Oracle4System@ORCLCDB AS sysdba;
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the port used WITHIN the container (I think this is the question), you could try building a new image after modifying the [conf file](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/18.4.0/oracle-xe-18c.conf), e.g. (for the 18c image).  The other images hard code the 1521 port in various files in that repo depending on the oracle version you are using, so those would have to be changed prior to building the image.

I have been using this image: `container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:latest`.  This is version 18c and it has a conf file within the image located at `/etc/sysconfig/oracle-xe-18c.conf`, I would just build a new Dockerfile and overwrite that file with a new one that has the port you require.  Or, you could extract the entire contents of that directory, dump it to a host directory, modify the file as needed, and map a volume to `etc/sysconfig` (*make sure the permissions are correct*). This way you could tweak the file from the host. It might be possible to set the variable in that conf file from an environment variable within a `docker-compose.yaml` file or on the `docker` command line. This variable is named `LISTENER_PORT`. Some of the variables in these scripts are defined locally and do not pull their values from environment variable though.